# How to make project version independent?

Tags: c#, console-application, dll

I am creating a console application. It uses third party `.DLL`. My PC has latest version (say 2.3.0.0). When I run this application on other PCs (by copying the `.exe` file), I get *`FileNotFound exception`* that it can not find the `.dll` with version 2.3.0.0. The other PC had version of 2.1.0.0 which will suffice based on

How do I tell , to not look for the specific version at run time ?

I know for compile time you can avoid this by setting *"Specific Version"* to false. But how about run time?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: I understand. In my situation, the clinet PC can have version of 2.0.0.0 or 2.1.0.0. For the newVersion attribute I can not specify the version range.

Comment: Take a look at this: [http://weblogs.asp.net/ralfw/archive/2007/02/04/single-assembly-deployment-of-managed-and-unmanaged-code.aspx](http://weblogs.asp.net/ralfw/archive/2007/02/04/single-assembly-deployment-of-managed-and-unmanaged-code.aspx)

Comment: I am not sure how I will I change my code. Isn't there any simple setting in app.config file that I can use ?